# How can I stream all audio from my imac into a PC on the same network?

Tags: macos, audio, streaming

I would like all iMac sounds to go through my network into my PC speakers. Is there an available solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be possible with [AirFoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/), but I've only personally used it to send audio between two Macs. They have a Windows version as well, though.

Comment: Yes. This is a good idea.

Comment: Ditto! AirFoil is great.